# Elasticsearch group by multiple fields and sum the hours (aggregation)

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am working on an elasticsearch(1.5) query to get all the tasks for users and their respective hours within a time interval. For example, 1st Jan 2016 - 31 Dec 2016.

This is what I have managed to get so far:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query" : {
        "bool" : {
          "must":
          {
            "term": {
              "userId": [1,2,3,4,5,6]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "spentOn": {
          "gte": "1451606400000", // 1st Jan 
          "lte": "1483142400000" // 31st Dec
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size":0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_interval": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "spentOn",
        "interval": "month",
        "min_doc_count": 0,
        "extended_bounds": {
          "min": "1451606400000", 
          "max": "1483142400000"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "group_per_project": {
          "histogram": {
            "field": "taskId",
            "interval": 1
          },

          "aggs": {
            "hours": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "hours"

              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above query gives me the following result:

```
{
...
[{
        "key_as_string" : "2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "doc_count" : 10,
        "group_per_project" : {
            "buckets" : [{
                    "doc_count" : 1,
                    "key" : Task A,
                    "hours_per_taskAssignment" : {
                        "value" : 5
                    }
                }, {
                    "doc_count" : 15,
                    "key" : Task  B,
                    "hours_per_taskAssignment" : {
                        "value" : 60
                    }
                }, {
                    "doc_count" : 1,
                    "key" :Task  C,
                    "hours_per_taskAssignment" : {
                        "value" : 10
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "key" : 1451606400000
    }, {
        "key_as_string" : "2016-02-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "doc_count" : 23,
        "group_per_project" : {
            "buckets" : [{
                    "doc_count" : 1,
                    "key" : Task A,
                    "hours" : {
                        "value" : 2
                    }
                }, {
                    "doc_count" : 20,
                    "key" : Task B,
                    "hours" : {
                        "value" : 180
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "key" : 1454284800000
    }
...
]
```

However, I need the hours to be grouped and summed by the user, instead of a summation of all the user's hours. For example in January:

```
{
 "doc_count" : 2,
 "key" : Task A,
 {
    "userId": 1
    "hours": {"value": 2}
 },
  {
    "userId": 2
    "hours": {"value": 5}
 }
}
```

Is there any way I can achieve the above result using ElasticSearch 1.5 without having to loop through each individual user and get the total hours and in doing so reducing the performance of the application?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_interval": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "spentOn",
        "interval": "month",
        "min_doc_count": 0,
        "extended_bounds": {
          "min": "1451606400000",
          "max": "1483142400000"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "group_per_project": {
          "histogram": {
            "field": "taskId",
            "interval": 1
          },
          "aggs": {
            "per_user": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "userId"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "hours": {
                  "sum": {
                    "field": "hours"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi Andrei, many thanks for your answer. I tried your solution and it give me the following for userId : "key": " \u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0012\fb". 
After some research I found that this is an issue with older versions (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/8614). Do you know how this can be resolved with ES 1.5? Thanks is advance.

Comment: Oh, that :-). Yeah, different types with the same fields and different field types can cause different sorts of issues. And there is a whole overhaul in 2.x specifically for eliminating those situations (enforcing mapping rules aggressively). So, you do have one index with multiple types that have `userId` fields that are both numeric and `string`?

Comment: Thanks Andrei, for your answer. It worked. :) I fixed the issue for dealing with multiple types by specifying the numeric version of userId. Once  amended the query it worked beautifully. Thanks again.